# Escape sequence \u001b[2D and \u001b[40C

Tags: terminal, ansi-escape

I came across this piece of text in my console output:

```
I:\u001b[2DA_O_T:\u001b[40C = -0.0
```

I know that `I:` and `A_O_T:` as well as `= -0.0` is normal output so I conclude that `\u001b[2D` and `\u001b[40C` are escape sequences.

But I couldnt figure out what they do. I looked them up here: http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php but couldn't find a match.

Does anyone know what `2D` and `40C` do in an escape sequence?

Comment: `\u001b` represents Esc.

Comment: @melpomene jeah I know that. Thats why you call it "Escape sequences".

Comment: "Esc[ValueD  **Cursor Backward:**"

Comment: Ah, okay - now I get it. So 40C is cursor forward. Thanks!